# How I can rewrite a url that contain a date on NGINX

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a problem with a rewrite url on wordpress.
The url looks like this: example.com/blog/2020-12
I would like to turn it into: example.com/blog/2020/12

I tried this unsuccessfully:

```
location ~ "^/blog/([0-9]{4}+)-([0-9]{2}+)/$" {
             rewrite ^(.*)-(.*) $1/$2 permanent;
         }
```

Comment: You have two `+` symbols in your regular expression that should be removed. Also the regular expression only matches a URI which ends with a `/`.

Comment: You are right, thanks Richard!
Now it works as it should.